# How to get response from Solidity Smart contract by Web3 client?

Tags: solidity, web3js

Here is the Smart contract code. I want to get the result of function of UserRegister by using web3.

```
 function UserRegister(string memory userName,uint feiyong ) public payable returns(string memory isOK,string memory resourceID){
   //address conAddr;
   emit LogContractAddress(msg.sender,address(this));
   emit LogData(msg.data);
   //byte userID=sha3(bytes(userName));
   if (bytes(users[userName].name).length==0){

       emit UserRegisterEVENT("null",userName);
       return ("null",userName);
   }
   else
   {
       emit UserRegisterEVENT("UserName has been registered","null");
       return("UserName has been registered","null");
   }
}
```

The web3 client code is as followings:

```
  var userName="def";
     var userReg=contract1.methods.UserRegister("abc",100).send({from:'0x18244fbf3b47175cd6b4a1183a476c9e70cb7368'})  .on('transactionHash', function(hash){
    console.log("hash="+hash);
}) .on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){
    console.log("confirmationNumber="+confirmationNumber+"receipt="+receipt.toString());
})
.on('receipt', function(receipt){
    // receipt example
    //receipt.
    console.log("receipt="+receipt.toString);
    } )
.on('error',function(error){

    console.log("error="+error);
})
;
```

and the result is as followings:

```
   hash=0x39e027a89c27d03e71ab2a310adefceca3dde48f668d2692705466501dff563e
confirmationNumber=0receipt=[object Object]
receipt=function toString() { [native code] }
confirmationNumber=1receipt=[object Object]
confirmationNumber=2receipt=[object Object]
confirmationNumber=3receipt=[object Object]
confirmationNumber=4receipt=[object Object]
confirmationNumber=5receipt=[object Object]
confirmationNumber=6receipt=[object Object]
confirmationNumber=7receipt=[object Object]
confirmationNumber=8receipt=[object Object]
confirmationNumber=9receipt=[object Object]
confirmationNumber=10receipt=[object Object]
confirmationNumber=11receipt=[object Object]
confirmationNumber=12receipt=[object Object]
confirmationNumber=13receipt=[object Object]
confirmationNumber=14receipt=[object Object]
confirmationNumber=15receipt=[object Object]
confirmationNumber=16receipt=[object Object]
confirmationNumber=17receipt=[object Object]
confirmationNumber=18receipt=[object Object]
confirmationNumber=19receipt=[object Object]
confirmationNumber=20receipt=[object Object]
confirmationNumber=21receipt=[object Object]
confirmationNumber=22receipt=[object Object]
confirmationNumber=23receipt=[object Object]
confirmationNumber=24receipt=[object Object]
```

How can i get the register result from smart contract ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

When sending the transaction like this:

```
const result = await smartContractObj.methods
        .methodToCall(parameter1, parameter2)
        .send( { gas: '5000000', from:masterAccount });
```

You get the event return value via:

```
result.events.UserRegisterEVENT.returnValues;
```

EDIT: Here is the complete Code

```
var myFunction = async () => {
    // Send the Transaction
    const result = await smartContractObj.methods
        .methodToCall(parameter1, parameter2)
        .send( { gas: '5000000', from:masterAccount });

    console.log("Transaction sent");

    // Get return value of the event
    return result.events.UserRegisterEVENT.returnValues;  
}
```

Just call the function. It will probably return an array. To get the value you need you should retrieve the output with a `console.log` once to get the value you need.

Edit2: With this code you can get from the Contract.

```
const result = await shoppingCart.methods.getCart(_cartID).call({from:masterAccount});
```

Works same as above put it in a async function.

You need to have a function like this in CONTRACT:

```
function getCart(uint _inputParam) public view returns(uint _obj){
        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97703/discussion-on-answer-by-pave-how-to-get-response-from-solidity-smart-contract-by).

Answer (score 0):

HeiHei.

You can't get return values of this function in transaction receipt.

But the good news is you can get parameters of UserRegisterEVENT event instead (judging by the code they are identical to function's return values).

Just check the `logs` property of `receipt` object in your `on('receipt')` handler.

Comment: thank you, But, receipt.log is undefined.  By the way, is there any way to get return values from the smart contract function ?  and How ? is there any tutorials about this?

Comment: you mentioned `receipt.log`. Is it a typo? You need `receipt.logs`. More here https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.1/web3-eth.html#gettransactionreceipt

Transaction return values (unlike call return values) are accessible only from another contract, i.e. when a contract calls another contract's function

Comment: But  how to get result from smart contract?

Comment: it's not possible